# Invalid cyrillic host header in Safari on iPhone 5S

Tags: php, ios, laravel, safari

Users with iPhone 5S can't open any page at Laravel 5.2 app.
I found this in logs:

```
UnexpectedValueException vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php in getHost
Invalid Host "%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB.%D1%80%D1%84"
```

I have a dumped this HTTP request and his really has a URL-encoded domain-name: `Host: %D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB.%D1%80%D1%84` header, instead of punycode version `xn--c1aay4a.xn--p1ai`

This is problem with web-server configuration or something?
Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am looking for a solution

Comment: By the way, the same problem on the desktop Safari

Answer (score 0):

The problem sending headers. You must manually convert uri in pynucode

```
$iWantRedirectTo = 'http://гугл.рф';

// http://xn--c1aay4a.xn--p1ai/
$uriWithPunycode = convert_to_punycode($iWantRedirectTo);

// It will work "Location: http://xn--c1aay4a.xn--p1ai/"
header('Location: ' . $uriWithPunycode);

//  Safari will not convert itself
header('Location: http://гугл.рф');
```